# Root domain in Azure FrontDoor configuration

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain, cname, azure-front-door

I am trying to set up the routing for the Apex/root domain of my website(myrootdomain.eu) in Azure FrontDoor.

Reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-how-to-onboard-apex-domain

Crated the Alias record with `@.myrootdomain.eu` in Azure DNS against the Azure resource as FrontDoor. A CNAME was created like this : `afdverify.myrootdomain.eu`

When i try adding the custom domain(`myrootdomain.eu`) into the frontend host of FrontDoor, it is giving the error CNAME record is not found. What additional step is required here .
Is there any setting or mapping to be done in my DNS 123domain or frontdoor for this domain : `afdverify.myrootdomain.eu`

What should be the mapping in domain provider (123domain in my case) for the naked domain(myrootdomain.eu) ?

Could not find any thing about that in the reference doc.

Comment: It takes a while to propagate across all DNS servers. You can check if the CNAME is effective or not using google dig tool- https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/

Comment: Is the issue fixed on your side? Is the reply helpful?

Comment: No. Not resolved. I dont understand how this would work without any mapping in Domian provider like 123domiain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [hosted your domain in Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns), (that is to edit the NS records and replace the NS records with the Azure DNS name servers in the registrar's DNS management page), you do not need to map in your original domain provider. It takes just a few seconds on my side to wait for the DNS taking place for the Apex/root domain in Azure Front Door.

After creating an alias record for zone apex, it creates a zone apex record pointing to your Front Door resource and also a CNAME record mapping 'afdverify' (example - `afdverify.contosonews.com`) to `afdverify.<name>.azurefd.net`.
[image]

If you have finished the above steps correctly, it usually takes some time for DNS propagation, you could check it via [whatsmydns](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) or [viewdns](https://viewdns.info/propagation/). As the comment said, you can check if the CNAME is effective or not using [nslookup](https://network-tools.com/nslookup/) or [google dig tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/).

[image]

Comment: I ended up adding a ANAME in my domain provider as i was able to update the NS records inside the provider.

Comment: What should I do with my www record? It was an A record pointing to my old IP, should I keep it A and alias it to FrontDoor or is it a CNAME aliased to Front Door?